# The method setHomeAsUpIndicator is undefined for the type ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, actionbardrawertoggle

I'm trying to use the support v4 `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in order to change the action bar indicator to a back arrow instead of the navigation drawer's 3 dots. I'm also using the v4 `Fragment`, v4 `Drawerlayout`, v7 `ActionBar` and v7 `ActionBarActivity`.

This is how I have used it:

in onCreate:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
```

When I try to change the indicators, I got no problems calling `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled` on the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` but I get the above error when trying to call `setHomeAsUpIndicator`. I can only call `setHomeAsUpIndicator` on `getSupportActionBar()`:

```
public void turnOnActionBarUpIndicator()
{
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null); //this compiles
    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(null); //this line does not compile
}
```

This results in the indicator's look being changed but not it's functionality meaning that I see an arrow as an indicator, but it opens up the drawer instead of going up the backstack.

How can I get both the look AND functionality of the `ActionBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably, if you've got a left drawer for navigation that can be opened up with a swipe from the left, you should always have the hamburger in the top left for opening it up. Makes your navigation hierarchy sorta messy, because it doesn't obey common conventions for how the hamburger menu works.

Second, the v4 toggle is deprecated, use v7.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this issue:
The import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved

Comment: v7 does include an actionbardrawertoggle. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Comment: OK so since I just can't seem to get it to work, I can't accept your answer. You can try help me with it and get 2 accepted answer if you can also answer this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555223/the-import-android-support-v7-app-actionbardrawertoggle-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: You're probably using an outdated version of the support library. Current version is 22.2.0; I'd wager you're importing something before 21.0.0. Double check what version you have downloaded via your sdk manager.

Comment: my libraries got Android 5.1.1.. that's 22 I believe

Comment: What's your gradle/maven dependency line? For gradle, should be 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

Comment: Are you using gradle to build? It'd be in your build.gradle.

Comment: I'm not in front of the dev computer right now and I'm not sure what I'm building with.. I'm just using Eclipse with the ADT..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79283/discussion-between-acco-and-yonatan-nir).